# How to get the the grammar from the parsetree in Rascal?

Tags: html, syntax, grammar, rascal, parse-tree

I am pretty new to this, but I have started coding Rascal and I have been stuck for a long time. I am trying to get the grammar of a parse tree, but I can't seem to manage to retrieve it.

You know the yellow boxes with grammars when you hover your mouse above the parse tree here?
http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Visualization/ParseTree/ParseTree.html#/Recipes/Visualization/ParseTree/ParseTree.html

I want to somehow get that. I am trying to visualize the parsetree on html. And I somehow think it is best to get the grammar and then draw the tree into html myself, or is there a better way of doing it?

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every parse tree node carries a representation of every grammar rule used. In the library module `Parsetree` you can find the definition of the Tree datatype. Each parse tree is of this type. Each `appl` term has a `Production` and a list of children of type `list[Tree]`.

Using pattern matching or field projection you can get at this data and draw your tree.

You can find example code in `vis::ParseTree`.

Also handy is the module `lang::rascal::format::Grammar` which has functions to pretty print grammar rule back in Rascal notation.